# When I open and close the pdf made by LaTeX in Acrobat, I can't work anymore on LaTeX

Tags: pdf, windows, acrobat

I recently have a problem with my LaTeX, that when I open the pdf produced by LaTeX in Acrobat, I can not reproduce it and I have to restart Windows, it also give an error that is:

```
\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty} \normalfont \cleardoublepage



\thispagestyle{empty}
%\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{-1.5cm} \bfseries{
\begin{center}
  \large
  POLITECNICO DI MILANO\\
  \normalsize
  Master Thesis in Mechanical Engineering\\
  Mechanical Engineering Department\\
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{./pictures/logopm}
%   \psfig{file=./pictures/logopm.jpg,width=3.5cm}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}
  \vspace*{0.3cm} \LARGE



  \textbf{TITLE OF THE THESIS}\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: close the acrobat windows before compiling the LaTeX document again.

Comment: I do that ,it doesnt help

Comment: try another  pdf viewer. i recommend sumatrapdf.

Comment: thank you , I forgot to mention , It has problem with this line :


  \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{./pictures/logopm}

Comment: Different PDF viewers have different responses to malformed PDF. Adobe Reader will sometimes find PDF problems that other readers miss (or the reverse). The problem with the PDF is not solved by using a different reader. Analogy: Bad HTML code may be displayed by one browser, but not by another browser. The problem is the code, not the browser.

Comment: @Farzad64 What is your error exactly? And you can add the missed information to your question rather than in a comment using `edit`.

Comment: This is probably a file lock on `logopm` or one of LaTeX's output files. Try to find the process holding this lock (http://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows) and kill it (eg. using Task Manager).